# Widget Customization for web AppBuilder

Tags: arcgis-web-appbuilder, widget

I am beginner for widget customization and I am trying to have a custom widget that has fade in and fade out functionality using a slider for a tiled map. I need to have the same functionality as the swipe widget, except it is slider unlike the swipe widget. 
Can I identify the basemap and the maplayer (tiled cached layer) so as to apply the fade in out function using the opacity property with dojo/javascript?

Comment: Are you definitely using the Boundless rather than ArcGIS web appbuilder?